# I can't center text on menu on my wp theme

Tags: css, menu, center

I can't find a way to center it.

http://milassoforlerodasi.org.tr/

My css codes goes like this:

```
/* First Level - Menu Secondary */
.menu-secondary li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 14px 3px 13px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Gentium+Basic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-secondary li a:hover, .menu-secondary li a:active, .menu-secondary li a:focus, 
.menu-secondary li:hover > a, .menu-secondary li.current-cat > a, .menu-secondary li.current_page_item > a, .menu-secondary li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: #000000;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    outline: 0;
}

/* Child Levels - Menu Secondary */

.menu-secondary li li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #000000;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-transform: none;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.menu-secondary li li a:hover, .menu-secondary li li a:active, .menu-secondary li li a:focus, 
.menu-secondary li li:hover > a, .menu-secondary li li.current-cat > a, .menu-secondary li li.current_page_item > a, .menu-secondary li li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #22AEEF;
    outline: 0;
}

/* Arrows - Menu Secondary */

.menu-secondary a.sf-with-ul {
    padding-right: 26px;
    min-width: 1px;
}
.menu-secondary  .sf-sub-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 0;
    top:  0;
    padding: 13px 13px 0 0;
}

.menu-secondary li li .sf-sub-indicator {

    padding: 9px 13px 0 0;
}

/* Shadows - Menu Secondary */

.wrap-menu-secondary .sf-shadow ul {
    background: url('images/menu-secondary-shadow.png') no-repeat bottom right;
}
```

I inserted many different codes into the `.menu-secondary li a` but none of them is really centering text and links.

Comment: `text-align: center` should do the job.

Comment: no it does not, sir.

Comment: @FıratPaskal i dont get it , it seems to be center

Comment: @FıratPaskal what r u expecting from the black menu

Comment: move your mouse over first and last text on menu and you will see the black gap at the end of the menu. So that means they are not really centered.

Comment: @FıratPaskal hmm ok , i will try to help u out

Comment: thank you sir. it's really complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got your question now.

Add a class `clearfix` in the `#menu-secondary-menu` element. 
Then add this css:

```
#menu-secondary-menu {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It should do the job.

Comment: Welcome. For centering inline elements you should do `text-align: center` and for centering block level elements `margin: 0 auto` will do the trick.